# Mongoose find by array of ids, but with repetitive results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider we have this array of IDs, which contains repetitive values.

```
[
 'A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'C',
 'C',
 'D',
 .
 .
 .
]
```

How can I select the match for each ID from the DB? I don't need unique rows. I mean the result array must contain three same rows for ID **C**. One to one pointing. thanks.

Comment: sorry, can you clarify a bit more? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidLuci I’m trying to get the match for each ID in my DB. $in returns unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it on the client-side since you may just create lots of duplicated data on server and return to client.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: {
        "$in": [ "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "fields": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "fields": {
        "$map": {
          "input": [ "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D" ],
          "as": "id",
          "in": {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                "findOne": {
                  "$first": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$fields",
                      "as": "item",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$item._id", "$$id" ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              in: {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": "$$findOne",
                  "then": "$$findOne",
                  "else": { _id: "$$id" }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$fields" }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_otQNKSIQhd)